# Android onTouchEvent() continuous touch causes system_server GC

Tags: android, touch, game-engine

I have a game that requires continuous touch to track user movement
and draws in SurfaceView. I've noticed that at about 30sec intervals
system_server will kick in with a GC and cause the game to stutter. If
I don't touch the screen at all system_server will be not GC. I'm
wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem before. I'm
using Canvas to draw around 30+ objects on screen at once and it runs
pretty smoothly (56fps) until system_server steps in... Is this
something inherit to SurfaceView? It looks like 3D games (using
GLSurfaceView) don't have this problem.

I'm developing on a Samsung Vibrant.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like placing a small delay in the onTouchEvent() will decrease the frequency of this GC by system_server, but it also decreases the responsiveness of my game... Doesn't look like there's a clean solution right now but hopefully Android 2.3 will fix this: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/412-android-23-brings-games-to-forefront

Comment: Update: I've finally solved my stuttering problem. I had two threads that handled the rendering and logic, most likely my implementation of this was very inefficient... After combining the logic and rendering into one thread the game play is smoooooth 56fps consistently :) system_server still gc's but the time it takes is only ~180ms instead of the 300ms~400ms

Comment: What do you mean you combined your logic and rendering into one thread? I would love to see an example of this type of implementation! I however too cause too much GC with touchEvents, when I don't touch there is only a single GC at the beginning of game.. that's nothing to worry about though. If I touch many times it creeps up there pretty bad..

Answer (score 0):

Do you allocate objects before you start the game? If you construct new objects and free old ones during the game, inevitably the GC will kick in.